# Django PythonAnywhere (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server (timed out)")

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to setup a Django project and I can't seem to connect to MySQL database made in PythonAnywhere.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'username$dbname',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
    }
}
```

I cant enter the database in the PythonAnywhere Bash with my user, host, name and password, but when i try to do it in django it appears as follows:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com' (timed out)")`

Comment: chekc your host that doesn't sseem to be right

Comment: I'm using the same host that I use in the pythonanywhere bash to enter the database and is the same one that appears in the connection value after doing the status command

Comment: Do you try to connect to that database from your local machine? If so, you need to use ssh tunnel. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't fix this error.
Installed MySQL Workbench and used localhost to run the database.
After that, I was able to run the following code:

```
DATABASES = {
     "default": {
         "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
         "NAME": "Mysql",
         "USER": "admin",
         "PASSWORD": "password",
         "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
         "PORT": "3306",
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add PORT in default database settings.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'username$dbname',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can connect to the database outside django. E.g.Via Shell or MySQLWorkBench.

Everything was working fine on my home wifi. But I encountered the same error when using a public wifi. It seemed the database provider I used (Azure) blocked the access. When this error occured, Shell connection and MySQLWorkBench would not work as well.